# Filling gap creates seams in shading with normal map

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, faces, normals

I had this gap in this model that I wanted to fix, so I filled it, which turned out fine after some tuning. When I applied a normal map- any normal map, it creates a seam from where I filled it, I tried smoothing out the normal map, editing the UV's, auto smoothing, and a few other techniques that didn't work.
[image]

In the solid mode, it looks completely fine, or when I don't use a normal map at all.
[image]

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: If you've created new faces, you need to make sure that they are correctly unwrapped, and that it's coherent with the rest of the UVs, if you're using the Texture Coordinate UV output of course, but maybe pack your normal map image and share your file?